# Delete Pandas top level columns in hierarchal index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataset like this

```
dataDate   prediction    original    
           Group pred
2018-09-30  A    2.30     3
2018-10-01  A    1.51     4
2018-10-02  A    2.08     5
2018-10-03  A    1.82     5
2018-09-30  B    0.96     2
```

I want to delete the column 'prediction' who includes another two columns, but since it is 1 level up, I wanted to do something like this

```
df.drop('prediction')
```

but it gives me an error

```
KeyError: "['prediction'] not found in axis"
```

logically it should have been possible.

Please help me to delete it via the upper-level column, as it will help me to delete all the cols under 'prediction' very easily

Comment: `reset_index()` and rename the columns

Comment: `df.drop('prediction', axis=1, level=0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) by first level:

```
df = df.drop('prediction', axis=1, level=0)
```

And then remove second level of MultiIndex by [`MultiIndex.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, it certainly helped